# HttpClient Exception When Requesting from a TLS 1.2 Only Endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2

Does anyone know how to get HttpClient to work with a site that only supports TLS 1.2. I've verified with SSL Labs, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sandbox.paypal.com, that paypal has turned off all but TLS 1.2 on their sandbox site.

When I run the following code, I get an exception with the message, "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = client
    .GetAsync("https://sandbox.paypal.com/")
    .Result;
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? 4.5 adds support for TLS 1.2, and would kick in automatically. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are correct Matt. I'm actually on 4.6 and if I inspect System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol, it's set correctly. My issue is the cert at sandbox.paypal.com is throwing an error that I'm not getting on other TLS1.2 only sites, thus confusing the results I'm getting.

Comment: Also worth noting, the default SecurityProtocol is TLS1|SSL3 up to .NET 4.5.2. It's not until 4.6 does it default to TLS11|TLS12.

Answer (score 0):

Their certificate is valid for `www.sanbox.paypal.com` but not for `sandbox.paypal.com`. Either add 'www' to the request URI or use custom certificate validation callback, like:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```